Magnitude of sum of projections is invariant under rotation of picture plane.
Suppose you are looking at two orthogonal vectors such that they appear as a single horizontal line on the picture plane. You are standing L distance from a pivot point C in the space. If you move to a different position equidistant from the pivot (i.e., move along the arc of circle whose center is C), would the total length of projections be unchanged?

Difficult to understand. You should draw a picture...
